# Is the Repository pattern a part of the Ports and Adapters concept

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design

Reading the blue book at page 152, we can find this:

> [A repository] provide methods to add and remove objects, which will
>   encapsulate the actual insertion or removal of data in the data store.
>   Provide methods that select objects based on some criteria and return
>   fully instantiated objects or collections of objects whose attribute
>   values meet the criteria, thereby encapsulating the actual storage and
>   query technology.

One of advantages in repositories introduction is that:

> They allow easy substitution of a dummy implementation, for use in
>   testing

Crystal clear! I can use an interface to define the repository; implement it with many classes (i.e. real database, rather than in-memory value for testing); inject one implementation or another using DI engine.

On the other hand:

> The hexagonal architecture (aka ports and adapters) divides a system into several
>   loosely-coupled interchangeable components, such as the application
>   core, the database, the user interface, test scripts and interfaces
>   with other systems.

To me it look like extend the repository concepts not only to a database. Do I have a notification port? Then I will implement two adapters one for RabbitMQ, another one for Amazon SNS or in-memory topic.

Put in this way, to me: **a repository could be considered an adapter for the database port.**

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, bang on.

A Repository pattern is a kind of port in an Hexagonal Architecture.

The difference is how far in/out you are zoomed.

The Repository pattern is a much more detailed perspective:

- zoomed out it might be just a port in your hexagonal architecture.
- zoomed out it might also be used in other architectures, such as a tiered architecture.

Comment: If the `IRepository` is the port, can I consider `MySqlRepository` or `MongoDbRepository` its adapters?

Comment: Yes. When you are considering it in terms of hexagonal architecture.